# Why are there so many free chrome extensions on the chrome web store?

Tags: chrome-web-store

I want to develop and monetize a video recorder and screen capture chrome extension but I fail to understand why there are so many free extensions on the Chrome Web Store. I see these as fierce competition for my extension since I want to offer In-App purchases. So, I ask, why is it there are so many free Chrome extensions and how do their developers make money?

Comment: Why even question it, man? :P

Comment: I question it because all those free extensions have made it near impossible to monetize ones new extensions:(

Comment: To monetize your extension, try providing a solution to a problem no one else has previously provided, or in an original/innovative way. If the quality of your product stands out, there will be people willing to pay for it.

Comment: Okay Ivan, I will try that. I have also noticed how some extension makers have a privacy policy stating how they get user data to enable them to conduct custom advertising. Some of these even sell that data to third parties. Do you recon I try that? It seems sort of unethical.

Comment: @John I think it's fine as long as you make your users aware of what you're doing with their information. The line of _ethics_ becomes a bit blurry if it's hidden within a lengthy ToS, but even then its legally your right (don't hold me accountable if this information is false as I am not a lawyer, but I'd assume that's how it works).

Comment: Hehe. Do you know of any companies that are willing to purchase user data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not all the extensions are developed by professional programmers who need to charge for them for a living. Many programmers develop extensions with the only purpose of providing a useful service. If they can offer that for free, I can't see why not.

In my case, I make money from my day job (completely unrelated to programming). I benefit from using free software (Linux) and my free extension is a way to contribute to the community.

Comment: Well, may I say that that is very surprising indeed. Google must be getting a lot of free labour to develop extensions for them then.

Comment: Many people see programming as a pet hobby they like to showcase. Just like many people like to blog, vblog, photoblog, and otherwise do something without directly monetizing the content. There's nothing wrong with that, they don't do it "for Google".

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the  intel.